# VB.net - MSaccess connection fail - already installed Access Database Engine 2016

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledbconnection

I need to make an application for my school project. The purpose of the app is getting information from a specific database and filter the desired data.

I made a test-database so I can already test it on vb.net. During the connection I keep getting the error 'The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine'.

So after getting the error , I made some research and found that I need to install Access Database Engine. However after I installed it , I keep getting the same error.

I have already changed the provider setting in vb.net to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

So I would like to ask you how I can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the target platform for your project? If it is anything that is or could be 64-bit then that is likely the issue. ACE is available in 32-bit and 64-bit but very few people install the 64-bit version. For that reason, any application that uses ACE needs to be exclusively 32-bit unless it is guaranteed that the users will have 64-bit ACE installed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i am sure that i installed the 64-bit version.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I use MS access 2016 and Visual studio 2017... In another site i read that it needs to be oledb.16.0.instead of oledb12.0. is that true ? and if it's true what do I need to install to get oledb.16.0 ?

Comment: You need to use 12. Try testing your connection string using Excel and the OLEDB function there

Comment: Who will you end-users be and will they have 32-bit or 64-bit ACE?

Comment: I solved the problem by converting my access database to mdb instead of accdb.